# How can I import a data frame from R saved as RData to pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, rpy2

I'm trying to import a data frame from R saved as RData to a pandas data frame. How can I do so? I unsuccessfully tried using rpy2   as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

# I use iris for convenience but I could have done r.load('my_data.RData')
print(r.data('iris'))
print(r['iris'].head())
print(type(r.data('iris')))

print(pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(r.data('iris')))
print(pandas2ri.ri2py(r.data('iris')))
print(pd.DataFrame(r.data('iris')))
```

outputs:

```
[1] "iris"

   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
1           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
3           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
4           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
5           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
<class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.StrVector'>
   0  1  2  3
0  i  r  i  s
['iris']
```

I use pandas 0.20.1 + python 3.6 x64 + Windows 7.

Comment: can perhaps use `rpy2` to open the `Rdata` and save each object as `csv`?

Comment: What is the error or undesired results? You may be showing it but not explaining. Do note `r.data() != .RData`. The former is a function that pulls in R's built-in datasets like iris, mtcars, etc. and the other is a binary file type.

Comment: @snoram I would prefer to avoid csv and stay in binary formats. The best alternative outside py2 that I'm aware of is feather.

Comment: @Parfait I would like a pandas data frame with the same  content and column names as the R data frame.

Comment: Again, *I unsuccessfully tried using rpy2* is not specific ... what is unsuccessful? What's wrong with first print? Is the type not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalized conversion of data frames turns out to be an expensive operation as a copying is required for some types of columns. A local conversion rule could be better:

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects import default_converter
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

print(r.data('iris'))
with localconverter(default_converter + pandas2ri.converter) as cv:
    pd_iris = r('iris')
# this is a pandas DataFrame
pd_iris
```

Otherwise, the following is "just working" on this end (Linux, head of branch default for rpy2):

```
import pandas as pd
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

pd_iris = r('iris')
pd_iris
```

If it does not for you, there might be an issue with rpy2 on Windows (yet an other one - rpy2 is not fully supported on Windows).